# How many N Links does root's index node have?

Tags: unix, filesystems

Title says it all really, but here's the prompt.

For an operating systems class, we have been given some base code for a file system and asked to expand it.

Part of that feature list includes making our own implementation of fschk, which needs to verify the number of links per index node is correct.

My fschk (right or wrong) walks the file system and reads the index node number from each filename. It then adds one to an index in a table which maintains a reference count. It then walks this table and compares the counted values to what each index node actually says.

This has given me the correct number of Nlinks for all new files and directories I've added to the filesystem, except the root node itself. I always count one reference to root from walking the filesystem, but root's index node insists that it has 3 Nlinks.

That's just what prompted me to ask this question. In a general Unix filesystem, how many Nlinks does root's index node have? Where do they come from?

Answer (score 0):

I've learned it's 3. The name itself, followed by the . and ..

1. `/`
2. `.`
3. `..`